# Why won't my discord bot go online? I get Typeerror Messages

Tags: python, debugging, discord.py

I am working on a discord bot, and it's not starting up. I run debugger, and it gives me this error: `TypeError: CommandTree.command() got an unexpected keyword argument 'none'`

The bot doesn't go online at all. I have copied directly from a tutorial to test out what's going on, and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands


token='hidden for privacy'


bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Running")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} Command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@bot.tree.command(none="hello")
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hello {interaction.user.mention}! This is a Slash Command")
    ephemeral=True

@bot.tree.command(name="say")
@app_commands.describe(thing_to_say="What should I say?")
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, thing_to_say: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{interaction.user.name} said: `{thing_to_say}`")


bot.run(token)
```

[here is the screenshot of the discord bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XF9x.png)

Comment: `@bot.tree.command(none="hello")` That should be `name=`, not `none=`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in line 20 of your code. Happens to the best of us. If you need any more help then you can DM me on discord RobertK#6151!

Fixed code:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands


token='hidden for privacy'


bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Running")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} Command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@bot.tree.command(name="hello") # instead of @bot.tree.command(none="hello")
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hello {interaction.user.mention}! This is a Slash Command")
    ephemeral=True

@bot.tree.command(name="say")
@app_commands.describe(thing_to_say="What should I say?")
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, thing_to_say: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{interaction.user.name} said: `{thing_to_say}`")


bot.run(token)
```

Comment: thank you! when i get home i'll be use this when I get home.